# Why wasn't the bounty awarded

Tags: support, bounty

I recently [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66709157/1426539) a question with a bounty.

I had 2 upvotes and the accepted answer.
It's been over 24 hours so why wasn't the bounty awarded?

[image]

Answer (score 12):

The bounty was not awarded, because at the time the bounty ended, your answer did not meet the criteria.

From the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) (emphasis mine)

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period),
> the highest voted answer created after the bounty started **with a
> minimum score of 2** will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full
> amount, if the answer is also accepted). If two or more eligible
> answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer
> is chosen. **If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is
> awarded to anyone.**

From your reputation tab, we can see that your answer received its second upvote and the accept on the 22nd of March at 21:17 and 21:18 respectively, hours **after** the grace period ended.

The grace period of the bounty ended on the 22nd of March at 17:03, by which time your answer only had a single upvote and was not accepted, hence not meeting the criteria.

The [Bounty Ended with no winning answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66476058/revisions).

Comment: the text states If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period)

Comment: Where does it mention that the upvote and accepted answer has to be within the bounty period and not the grace period

Comment: If anything the documentation probably need to be written more explicitly wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @johnny5 The 22nd of March at 17:03, _was_ the end of the grace period. The bounty started at the 14th, so the regular end of the bounty was on the 21st, not the 22nd.

Comment: I'm aware, but the documentation is not clear on the rules there. The documentation is explicitly inclusive of the.grace period

Comment: @johnny5 Your answer didn't qualify for bounty auto award **during the grace period**. Read Ivar's answer again. Your understanding of the docs is correct. You simply are confused about the order of events in the timeline.

Comment: @yivi oh thanks for the clarification.  That makes sense now